# Laplace transform giving incorrect result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inverse, integral-transforms

In Mathematica:

```
LaplaceTransform[Exp[-Exp[-t]], t, s]
Out:= Gamma[s]-Gamma[s,1]
```

But performing `InverseLaplaceTransform` on the result does not give me any output. Even `InverseLaplaceTransform[Gamma[s], s, t]` does not give any output, but `InverseLaplaceTransform[-Gamma[s,1], s, t]` returns `Exp[-Exp[-t]]` which is identical to my input. Does that mean `InverseLaplaceTransform[Gamma[s], s, t]`=0 according to Mathematica?

Integration by summing residues shows that inverse Laplace transform of Gamma function is:
$$\mathbf{L^{-1}}[\Gamma(s)]=\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}ds~e^{st}\Gamma(s)\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty Res_{s=-n}[e^{st}\Gamma(s)]\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nt}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(e^{-t})^n}{n!}=e^{-e^{-t}}$$

in which `Gamma[s,1]` has no role! I have verified by numerically inverting the Laplace transform (using Talbot's method) that presence of `Gamma[s,1]` indeed doesn't matter at all (i.e. whether I invert `Gamma[s]` or `Gamma[s]-Gamma[s,1]` I get the same number and this matches with `Exp[-Exp[-t]]`). I know this is a broad question, but what is going on with Mathematica here?

Comment: I confirm that it did not work for me (Mma 11.3, Win7).

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
sol = Sum[LaplaceTransform[(-Exp[-t])^j/j!, t, s], {j, 0, Infinity}]

(*Gamma[s, 0, 1] *)

InverseLaplaceTransform[sol, s, t]

(* E^-E^-t *)
```

Comment: My main objection is why `InverseLaplaceTransform[-Gamma[s,1], s, t]=Exp[-Exp[-t]]` without `Gamma[s]` which is also a part (and an important part, as integration by residue shows) of its own output?